# How to move to next Macintosh field from a popup?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion

I'm used to on Windows of using the keyboard to choose a popup combo box menu item in a window and then once it is selected, using the tab key to move to the next field for entry.

I'm finding this does not work for Chrome on Macintosh OS X Lion.

What is the keyboard key to use in this case?

Here is an example, 05/08/12 is selected using keyboard, now want to tab to Next button with a single keystroke and choose the current item of 05/08/12 (presently must first hit space, and then hit tab, two keystrokes):

[image: Here is an example, 05/08/12 is selected using keyboard, now want to tab to Next button with a single keystroke and choose the current item of 05/08/12]

Comment: In that situation, you can really only select the date with `space` or `return`, then `tab` through the form elements until you're at the *Next* button. But maybe I'm not understanding you correctly — is your real question whether you can `tab` right away without selecting the date?

Comment: Correct, the date is highlighted already, so I want a single key to press that both selects it and moves to the next field, just like it works on a Windows machine.

Comment: I'm almost entirely sure that this is not possible in OS X.